# React and Bootstrap columns are not working together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am just jumping into React, as my first project I wanted to convert a Bootstrap project into React and Bootstrap.

What I had was:

```
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="btn heading_button col-xs-12" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                            <h4> Header </h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="collapseTwo">
                            <span>
                                Content
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

It was an expanding header that look like this: 
[image]
[image]

My React version so far looks like

```
var Campaign_Setup = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        // transferPropsTo() is smart enough to merge classes provided
        // to this component.
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="btn heading_button col-xs-12" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">
                                <h4> Header</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div id="collapseTwo">
                                <span> Content </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
      }
    });

React.renderComponent(<Campaign_Setup />, document.getElementById('Campaign_Settings'));
```

But it turns out

[image]

[image]

The header is supposed to take up the whole width, but the React version is squeezing it, and the arrow icon, created in CSS with:

```
.heading_button:before {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';  /* essential for enabling glyphicon */
    content: "\e114";    /* adjust as needed, taken from bootstrap.css */
    float: right;        /* adjust as needed */
    color: #999999;         /* adjust as needed */
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

doesn't render. What is wrong with this?
It's worth noting that when looking in the inspector. The container, and rows fill the width, but the button/header does not.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to convert one `class` into `className` for `Content`.

There should be a warning in your console.