# React.js attributes on tr gets discarded

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building an app with react.js and bootstrap for react. I am trying to create a table row with class "success". However, passing attribute "class" to tr tag in react does not work, in the translated HTML there is no attribute whatsoever.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <ReactBootstrap.Table bordered striped hover>
        <thead><tr><th>name</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr class="success"><td>Jonas</td></tr></tbody>
    </ReactBootstrap.Table>
  }
});
```

Related JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7pqrwfch/

Comment: You should use the unminified build, it'll give a warning about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [React and Bootstrap columns are not working together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616319/react-and-bootstrap-columns-are-not-working-together)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `className` instead:

```
<tr className="success">
```

*(Read the note here: [JSX in Depth](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html))*